# Why not use Den?

Tags: accusative, nominative

In my textbook I had to make a sentence *im Präsens* using the verb `anfangen` and `mit der Arbeit.` I don't understand that the textbook says it should be *Ich fange mit **der** Arbeit an* instead of *Ich fange mit **den** Arbeit an*.

Why is it *der Arbeit* nominative instead of accusative?

Comment: `der Arbeit` is dativ because `mit etw. anfangen` requires a dativ object. The preposition `mit` is almost always followed by dativ.

Comment: The main point you seem to be missing is that _die Arbeit_ is a feminine noun. Also, _mit_ always governs dative, no exceptions here.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. You're right. Thought it said der arbeit in the dictionary bus it was die x)

Comment: @jankees Quick addition: If it were “der Arbeit” instead of “die Arbeit”, the correct sentence would be „Ich fange mit deM Arbeit an.“, and not „Ich fange mit deN Arbeit an.“ This is due to the preposition “mit”, which is followed by a dative.

Answer (score 8):

The word *Arbeit* is female:

```
Nominativ: die
Genetiv:   der
Dativ:     der
Akkusativ  die
```

but *mit* requires the the 3rd case (Dativ).

Comment: Gute antwort, kurz und bündig!